# how to pass a parameter to the method in the following case?

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing

In the following code if `retString` is a method name , then how do I pass a parameter to that method if it has one?

Comment: Does the method accept parameters?

Comment: One of the method accepts parameter.

Comment: Did you read the collections examples and doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **Method** object to invoke methods. And then use the [invoke()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) method of the *Method* class to well, invoke the method you intend to run. And there you pass parameters, like:

```
Object o = m.invoke(t, new Locale(args[1], args[2], args[3]));
```

( that is a snippet from the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) )

Comment: "didnt work" is not something we could help with. Please read [mcve] really *carefully* - and then consider writing up a new question, showing exactly what you did and what kind of error you run into ... and feel free to drop me a comment then; and I might have a look into that (tomorrow maybe).